# If $(u_n)$ is a fundamental sequence, then $(u_n^+) =(\max(u_n, 0))$ is also a fundamental sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I cannot find the definition of a fundamental sequence somewhere else except in the book functional analysis by Michel Willem. It looks like this name is not very common. Here is the definition.

A fundamental sequence is an increasing sequence $(u_n) \in \mathcal{L}$ such that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\Omega} u_n d \mu = sup_n \int_{\Omega} u_n d \mu < \infty. 
$$

Here is my attempt. Since each $u_n \in \mathcal{L}$, each $u_n^{+} \in \mathcal{L}$. $(u_n^+)$ is increasing everywhere, which can be easily checked. Finally, we need to check $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\Omega} u_n^+ d \mu < \infty$. I don’t know if it is correct. But I think there are 4 cases to consider.

Case 1: $u_n^{+} = u_n$ everywhere. Since $(u_n)$ is a fundamental sequence, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\Omega} u_n d \mu  < \infty$. It follows that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\Omega} u_n^+ d \mu =  \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\Omega} u_n d \mu < \infty$.

Case 2: $u_n^+ = 0$ everywhere, Then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\Omega} u_n^+ d \mu = 0$.

Case 3 $u_n^{+} = u_n$ almost everywhere and Case 4: $u_n^{+} = 0$ almost everywhere.

I have a hard time proving case 3 and case 4 even though it is kind of obvious the limit of integral is bounded. I don’t know if proving by cases is the best way to prove this statement. Any suggestion about how to prove case 3 or case 4 will be great. If you have suggestions about different proof, that will be great, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$u_n \geq u_1$ implies that $u_n^{-} \leq u_1^{-}$. Since $u_1$ is integrable it follows that $\int u_1^{-}<\infty$ and hence $\sup_n \int u_n^{-} <\infty$. Now $\sup_n \int u_n^{+} =\sup_n \int [u_n^{-}+u_n]<\infty$.